# #include standard files in more than one .cpp, versus #include it in precompiled header affects size of executable?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, visual-c++

1. In MS Visual Studio compiler: including standard library header, like `<vector>` or `<iostream>`. Does it make a difference in the size of resulting binary if those are included more than once in some `.cpp` files compared to including it once in precompiled header (which is eventually getting included in all those and all other `.cpp` files in the project)?
2. Same question for non standard library includes. Includes of custom headers of a static library. (If it depends on data size defined in those headers/libraries, then yes, assume there are some definitions.)
3. What about gcc/Linux environment? Does gcc have precompiled header concept? (If not, consider just some common header that's included in all .cpp files)

Comment: No. Precompiled headers is a way of improving compile time.

Comment: There should not be a change in the size of the actual executable image. The executable file may differ in size slightly, perhaps, due to slightly different debug data present in the executable file.

Comment: The first two questions essentially answer themselves once you know what [precompiled headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954167/precompiled-headers) are. As for the third question: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for question 1 and 2 combined: (it does not matter if it is custom header or standard header)

If the header does not introduce static global variable, including this header in multiple `.cpp` file should not affect the size of resulting binary.

If the header does introduce static global variable, each `.cpp` that includes this header with have their own version of static initializer for that variable, adding to the size of resulting binary. One example is `cout,cin,clog,cerr` in `iostream`.

For this reason, avoid including `iostream` in common header/precompiled header (use `ostream` instead as it does not introduce static global variable). Include `iostream` into `.cpp` files that actually need it.

You might also want to try link-time optimization. For MSVC, use `/GL /O2` in compile flag and `/LTCG` in link flag. For gcc/clang, use `-flto`.

(I skipped question 3 since Cody Gray already showed the link in comment)

Reference: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94794

Comment: If the header introduce a static global variable, how would it affect the binary's size?