# Basic console print program

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Main ()
{
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------/n";
    cout << "NAME: Justin Chiang/n";
    cout << "COMPUTER LANGUAGES: Python, Lua, C++/n";
    cout << "FAVORITE VIDEO GAME: Starcraft, Diablo/n";
    cout << "I'm taking this class for math undergrad requirement and because it is very useful." << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HW1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  HW1.cpp
1>c:\users\asus\desktop\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(5): warning C4627: '#include <iostream>': 
            skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\asus\desktop\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(25): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file 
            while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include  
            "StdAfx.h"' to your source?
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?` Troubleshooting a build failure couldn't possibly get any easier!

Comment: @Prætorian So where in the C++ standard does it say that every C++ program must begin with `#include "stdafx.h"`?

Comment: Please don't develop the habit of putting [system("pause")](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html) at the end of every program you write. It's non-portable and just makes your program less useful.

Comment: @john read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903228/why-use-precompiled-headers-c-c) on why you might possibly use a precompiled header.

Comment: @Rapptz I'm sure it's a good read, and I have nothing against precompiled headers at all. But I'm not seeing any indication that the OP is trying to use precompiled headers and failing. He's just created his first ever program and is getting a stupid error message about something he's never heard of.

Comment: @john Unless the OP went about creating his project file by hand, VisualStudio would've asked him if he wanted to use precompiled headers, which he didn't uncheck. So, instead of trying to get the OP to share your apparent dislike of precompiled headers, assume for a minute he knew what he was doing and answer his question!

Comment: @Prætorian You could be right, but I seriously doubt it. Much more likely he didn't know what the question meant and just accepted the default. Anyway the OP has all the information he needs now. He can pick what ever advice he thinks best.

Comment: What's with the `/n`? It's `\n` for new line.

Answer (score 3):

Go to project properties. Click on Configuration Properties/C/C++/Precompiled Header and pick the 'Not Using Precompiled Headers' option. The precise instructions might vary depending on exactly which version of Visual Studio you are using but basically you want to turn off precompiled headers.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `#include "stdafx.h"`

Also, `int Main()` isn't standard C++, you should replace your main function with `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)`

Since I have to say why you have to use a precompiled header, it makes compilation times faster with MSVC but it hinders portability and drags a lot of nonstandard conforming code if used. It's possible that it ruins your portability but you could easily just remove the header file if you're working with another IDE.

Comment: Which must be included before all other headers

Comment: He's not 'missing stdafx.h', he written a perfectly good C++ program which Visual Studio is refusing to compile because he has inadvertently turned on some non-standard options in the compiler.

Comment: @john `int Main() { ... }` is not a perfectly good C++ program

Comment: @john is `int Main()` perfectly good C++? It isn't standard, at the very least.

Comment: @Prætorian, OK lets assume that's a typo. In any case not the question he is asking about.

Comment: @john his question states "Why does this not compile", the answer is because of his error which states he has to include "stdafx.h".

Comment: @Rapptz Personally I wouldn't take programming advice from the literal interpretation of compiler error messages. VC++ seems particularly bad at giving poor advice this way.

Comment: what should I put instead of int main() then? I added #include "stdafx.h" now at the header....

Comment: -1 advicing a beginner to include the IDE-specific `<stdafx.h>` file is the entirely wrong thing to do.

Comment: @JustinChiang it's case sensitive. Does it compile now?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf if he had wanted to port this somewhere else nothing is stopping him from removing the header file before porting it.

Comment: @Rapptz what is  the sense of including a header if it isn't actually needed by the code in question?

Comment: @Rappts: advicing a beginner to include the IDE-specific `<stdafx.h>` file is the entirely wrong thing to do. since the OP's problem is that he doesn't know what's going on, that's stopping him from removing the header file. your answer does not nothing to help with that, and on the contrary it encourages totally unnecessary bad practice.

Comment: @juanchopanza precompiled headers in Visual Studio provide a faster compilation time since C++ compile times in Visual Studio are sometimes very slow without them.

Comment: @Rapptz: most people correcting you here *know* all that. they also know that with msvc precompiled headers (1) are msvc-specific, (2) allows some non-standard code to compile, and (3) prevents some standard code from compiling. which apparently you don't know. why are you *arguing*. you should just be thanking people for correcting you.

Comment: Then you can probably nuance your answer a bit, mention benefits/drawbacks of such an include.

Comment: I found out the main problem! I did not start an empty project and it was pre-configured. Thank you for all who told me to check header configuration properties.

Answer (score 0):

`int Main ()` should be in lower case. Change it to `int main ()`.

And

Change `cout << "... /n";`  to `cout << "... \n";`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "NAME: Justin Chiang\n";
    cout << "COMPUTER LANGUAGES: Python, Lua, C++\n";
    cout << "FAVORITE VIDEO GAME: Starcraft, Diablo\n";
    cout << "I'm taking this class for math undergrad requirement and because it is very useful." << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```